# Which subsets are vector spaces of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the vector space F(ℝ,ℝ). Which ones of the following subsets are vector subspaces of V ? Justify your answer!
(a) {f ∈ V | f(1) = 0} 
(b) {f ∈ V | f(0) = 1}
(c) {f ∈ V | f only has a finite number of zeros}
(d) {f ∈ V | f has infinitely many zeros}

I do not know how to proceed. Could you please give me a hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, what does it take for a subset to be a subspace?  List all the properties you need (there aren't many).  Then, for each candidate, see which properties are satisfied or not.  Many of these things are effortlessly seen ...for instance, is the additive identity in the subset?

Comment: is $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ just functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself?

Comment: @qbert yes, you are right

Comment: There are four parts to the problem.  I suspect this exercise was assigned to reinforce learning material recently covered in your textbook or classroom lectures.  Can you relate the definitions or propositions that seem to you to apply here?

Answer (score 1):

For problem d, my hint would be to examine the following functions
$$
f_1(x)=\begin{cases}0 &x>0\\1 &x\leq0 \end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
f_2(x)=\begin{cases}1 &x>0\\0 &x\leq0 \end{cases}
$$
specifically, their sum.

Comment: Good point, I fix!

Answer (score 0):

A non-empty subset of a vector space is a subspace if it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

For example in case of (b) if $$f(0)=1$$ and $$g(0)=1,$$ then $$(f+g)(0)=2\ne 1$$ which indicates that this set is not closed under addition.

Now you can proceed and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a subspace all the following three properties must be satisfied:

$1) \ \vec{0} \in W\\
2) \ \vec{v}+\vec{w} \in W\\
3) \ \vec{cv}\to c \cdot \vec{v} \ ,c \in \mathbb{R}$

Then note for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

- (a) {f ∈ V | f(1) = 0}

$$\vec 0\in V\quad f_1(1)+f_2(1)=0 \quad cf(1)=0$$

- (b) {f ∈ V | f(0) = 1}

$$\vec 0\not\in V$$
$$f_1(0)+f_2(0)=2$$

- (c) {f ∈ V | f only has a finite number of zeros}
  $$\vec0\not\in V$$
  $$f_1(x)=0 \iff x=0 \quad f_2(x)=0 \iff x=1$$
  $$f_1+f_2\neq0$$
- (d) {f ∈ V | f has infinitely many zeros}

$$\vec0\in V$$

but refer to [qbert example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2660583/505767).